# Samba Shares Fail - Pre-Authentication Failed

Tags: ubuntu, centos, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux, kerberos

Good day,

We have multiple HPCs (RHEL, CentOS, Ubuntu) running samba shares so that user can easily transfer files back and forth.  About 3 months ago, the DCs/AD got a refresh, redundancy (2 servers) and since then our samba shares sporadically fail for: `systemctl status smb`

[image]

Now, no passwords have been changed, sssd still allows domain users to login and shows no errors.  It must be a kerberos/smb issue.  Happy to share whatever config files needed to try to resolve this.

Comment: Please share at least SOME logs to begin with, rather than waiting for us to ask for that.

Comment: And please no images - share the text as text.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  The text in the image cannot be deciphered.  You are going to have to provide a great deal of diagnostic information.  What you have provided, to be frank, isn't enough to even begin to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Preauthentication failed" is Kerberos-speak for "Wrong password".

Your logs show that the message relates to a *machine* account (due to it being named `____$`, which you fortunately didn't cut off in your logs), so in Windows terms, this is the "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" error, because

Even though you say no passwords have been changed, generally AD member hosts change their machine account passwords **automatically** on a schedule, every 30 days or so, so getting this message likely means:

a) this machine's password change did not correctly replicate from the AD domain controller it was made at to the other DCs, or b) the AD DCs were restored from backups; meaning the DCs still expect the old password while the machine is trying to use the new one.

The specific message is due to your SSSD trying to connect to AD (probably to fetch user account information), but the same machine account password is also used to verify Kerberos tickets for incoming connections, so if it gets desynchronized from AD, the server will not be able to accept any NTLM or Kerberos ticket-based connections anymore.

Since it sounds like your network moved from having 1 DC to having multiple, I would kind of suspect that replication between them is having issues, and that needs to be solved on the DC side first. On your side, though, you'll likely have to reset the machine account password (e.g. re-join the servers).

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering.  I didn't include logs because there are a lot of long logs, was hoping there was something specific I could provide instead of overloading the thread, but we go. Too long to post, so here a text doc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x1qAoT6k15CL2LFKdZRYYxSmA69Ol2FL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: oh, on the note of re-joining.  This kerberos/samba issue has occured three time now this year, I've re-joined to temporarily solve it, however I need to stop it from reoccuring.

Comment: replication seems to be error free C:\Windows\system32>Repadmin /replsummary
Replication Summary Start Time: 2024-03-27 10:28:39
 
Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:
  .....
 
 
Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
SEA-DC1                   30m:11s    0 /   5    0
SEA-DC2                   36m:10s    0 /   5    0
 
 
Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error
SEA-DC1                   36m:10s    0 /   5    0
SEA-DC2                   30m:11s    0 /   5    0
 
 
C:\Windows\system32>Repadmin /Queue